# How to access properties of a command object from another command object?

Tags: grails, properties, groovy, controllers

I am currently working on a grails application. I have two command objects (AccountInfoCommand and EducInfoCommand) in a controller. On my EducInfoCommand, I wanted to check if the yearGraduated property is earlier than the set birthDate(a property of AccountInfoCommand) on its validator constraints. How will I do that?

This is my code for my AccountInfoCommand:

```
class AccountDetailsCommand  implements java.io.Serializable {

    String username
    String password
    String confirmPassword
    String emailAddress
    Date birthDate        
}
```

This is my code for EducInfoCommand:

```
class EducInfoCommand implements java.io.Serializable {

    Integer graduated 
    EducationLevel educationLevel   
    String schoolName 
    String yearGraduated
    String honorsReceived
}

static constraints = {

    yearGraduated nullable: false, maxSize:4, blank: false,  matches: /([0-9]*)/,
      validator: {
            Date.parse('yyyy',it) <= new Date() ? true : false
      }
}
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need some reference to which AccountDetails the EducInfo is for.  For example, if you added a username field to the `EducInfoCommand` you could look up the account details from that (assuming there is an AccountDetails gorm object which is similar to the command object):

```
class EducInfoCommand implements java.io.Serializable { 
    String yearGraduated
    String username
    // ...
}

static constraints = {
    yearGraduated nullable: false, maxSize:4, blank: false,  matches: /([0-9]*)/,
      validator: { val, obj ->
            Date.parse('yyyy',val) > AccountDetails.findByUsername(obj.username).birthDate
      }
}
```

Comment: Im so sorry, this isn't working. Null pointer exception error is thrown.

Comment: You will need to populate the username field appropriately.given that, you should probably add a nullable: false constraint for it.